How to add legend when we have one grouping variable in KM Plots
I am using ggsurvfit package to create KM plots. I am having one grouping variable and looking to add legend for that variable.

Please check code below: I am looking to add legend to this particular plot.
library(ggsurvfit)
survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df_colon) %>%
  ggsurvfit(color = "#508050") +
  add_confidence_interval(fill = "#508050") +
  add_risktable() +
  scale_ggsurvfit()

How can we add legend in the above-mentioned km plot?

A simple way would be to add aes() to the plot, mapping color and fill aesthetics to the string you wish to appear in the legend. Again, include manual scales to specify the actual colors you wish to appear.
survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df_colon) %>%
  ggsurvfit() +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable() +
  scale_ggsurvfit() + 
  aes(color = "Your label here", fill = "Your label here") +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = "#508050") +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = "#508050") +
  theme(legend.position = "right")


